# Grouping different 'names' into one

Tags: sql, oracle

My current data looks bad for what i'm trying to do. I have multiple columns that makes up a location ID, one of this columns is a location description. My problem is if the location is a 'Container', the description column  contains the Container ID instead of the word 'Container'

In my example if it's a number then it's a 'Container'

```
Location_desc | Qty
--------------------
Location A    | 10
Location A    | 10
Location B    | 20
Location B    | 20
ABC-123456    | 5
DEF-987654    | 5
```

I want to sum the qty column and grouping them by location, but I want my results to be like this

```
 Location | Total
 ----------------
 Location A | 20
 Location B | 40
 Container  | 10
```

Comment: show the query you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CASE` to fix locations:

```
select location, sum(qty) as total
from (select case when Location in ('Location A','Location B') then Location
             else 'Container' end as location,
             qty from tablename)
group by location
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of length and Translate as suggested [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/isnumeric.php)

```
select location_name, sum(qty) from (
select decode(Length(TRANSLATE(Location_desc, ' +-.0123456789', ' ')),null,'Container',Location_desc) location_name, qty
from YOUR_TABLE) group by location_name
;
```

Hope helped you!